# Failed to resolve third party library dependencies in Gradle in Androidstudio

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

When I try to give third party library dependencies it shows

> Error:(72, 13) Failed to resolve: com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1 Show in File
>   Show in Project Structure dialog

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
 }
}
```

this is my build.gradle.
I was migrated my project from Eclipse to Androidstudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your top level gradle file needs to point to a maven library source. See below.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey seriously its working dude, thanks but i have doubt. I also migrated another one project from eclipse to android studio. In that project also i added some third party library dependencies, it was working with same repositories with mavenCentral(). how?

Comment: @palanivelraghul what'd you mean?